# Adding .cs in a ResourceDictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, silverlight-4.0, expression-blend

I have DataTemplate in a ressource dictionnary, and in some, I need button and i don't know how i can use code behind for manage events.

I tried to put a class in my resource dictionnary like that :

```
<ResourceDictionary 
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   x:Class="SLProject.Templates"
   x:Class="TVTemplate">
```

And I definied the class in the cs file like that :

```
namespace SLProject.Templates
{
    partial class TVTemplate
    { 

    }
}
```

The build is OK but when the application started, I obtains XAML error following :

> AG_E_PARSER_BAD_TYPE

I tried all I know like change the class kind to a ClassModifier, make the class to an inherited class of RessourceDictionnary ... no way.

Someone have an idee ...

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Using the `x:Class` attribute allows you to define a codebehind for a `ResourceDictionary`.
You must specify the complete namespace of the class (i.e. `x:Class="WpfApplication.MyClass"`), and such class has to be defined as `partial` (at least VS 2010 complains and does not compile without such modifier).

I mocked-up a simple example:

**1.** Create a new WPF application project (**WpfApplication**)

**2.** Add a new class file (*TestClass.cs*) and paste the following code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    public partial class TestClass
    {
        private void OnDoubleClick(object obj, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Double clicked!");
        }
    }
}
```

**3.** Add a new `ResourceDictionary` (*Resources.xaml*), open the file and paste the following code

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    x:Class="WpfApplication.TestClass">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <EventSetter Event="Label.MouseDoubleClick" Handler="OnDoubleClick"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**4.** Finally, open the *MainWindow.xaml* and past the following code

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources.xaml"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="Double click here..." HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Background="Red"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In the example I wire-up a double-click event from a `Style`, since it is a scenario requiring you to call some code from a `ResourceDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

You have the x:Class attribute defined twice, which is why you're getting the parser error.  Change your declaration to this and it should work:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   x:Class="SLProject.Templates.TVTemplate">
```

Comment: I Checked, and it's just an error of copy-past. I have well the class definied one time.

Answer (score 0):

I Checked, and it's just an error of copy-past. I have well the class definied one time.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing would be to make your own usercontrol and add your events in it . and later put this entire usercontrol in resource dictionary.